# How do I migrate content from old a reference list to another in contentful?

Tags: contentful

I have a content type ("`group`") in contentful, that contains an Array ("`link_list`"). `link_list` accepts multiple entries of content type `old_link`Now I am wondering, since I have a list of `old_link`s with it's content, how do I take each entry of the list and convert it to the new content type `new_link`?

I've created a new field already: `new_link_list`, but how do I copy the content of each element from `link_list` to `new_link_list`?

`old_link` and `new_link` are not exactly the same, but share two fields ('slug', 'linktext') which is the content I want to be copied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Contentful CLI - space migration command](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-cli/tree/master/docs/space/migration) to derive the "new_link" entries from the "old_link" entries and and associate them to the "group" types "new_link_list" field

The script file would use [deriveLinkedEntries](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-migration/blob/master/README.md#derivelinkedentriesconfig) and look something like this:

```
migration.deriveLinkedEntries({
  contentType: 'group',
  derivedContentType: 'new_link',
  from: ['link_list'],
  toReferenceField: 'new_link_list',
  derivedFields: ['slug', 'linktext'],
  identityKey: async (fromFields) => {
    return fromFields.slug['en-US'].toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')
  },
  shouldPublish: true,
  deriveEntryForLocale: async (inputFields, locale) => {
    return {
      inputFields.slug[locale],
      inputFields.linktext[locale]
    }
  }
})
```

*Note:* You might need to change the behavior of `identityKey` if the slug value is not unique.